# Alien hunger games like book including 12 people below 21

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I was reading a hunger games style alien scifi trilogy about "The Others" who were in earth and told humans to farm for gold for them and before they left they told them that they'd be back to judge a battle between them and whoever wins gets the planet basically. In the book there were 12 people in total who were fighting while the rest of the world was oblivious but on of the characters was names sara and she died with 2 others after getting off at a airfield by getting sniped by the another participant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a paperback, a hard cover, or an ebook?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58438205-the-chosen-twelve popped up with the keywords, but doesn't seem to match other than involving twelve winners from a Hunger Games kind of fight.

Comment: It was a hard cover and soft cover.. It was a young adult but had a darker theme and more adult sensitive subjects involved. Such as mental illness and loss of life. It was about 4 yrs ago that I read this.

Answer (score 4):

This is likely *Endgame* by James Frey (2014).

From the summary: "Twelve teens who have prepared their entire lives for an ancient life-or-death game must finally come to terms with its arrival, forming tenuous alliances and killing each other for the chance to be the last one standing and the winner of the ultimate prize: the ability to save a select group of people from the end of the world." [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Calling.html?id=P1XXsgEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description)

The main character is named Sarah. You can read detailed reviews here: [Goodreads reviews of Endgame](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22664220-the-calling)